# Python Socket Programming: Application freezes when connecting to a server

Tags: python, sockets, windows-8, network-programming

I am new to socket coding in Python, and I wrote this simple function to connect to a server. It runs in a tkinter window. I have an `Entry` widget, and it is where you input the IP address of the server to connect to. However, when you click the button to connect, the application hangs and freezes. Here is the code below.

```
def Test(self):
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(5)
    lengthInfo = self.lengthEntry.get()
    if self.portEntry.get() != '':
        portInfo = int(self.portEntry.get())
    serverInfo = self.serverEntry.get()
    conn = socket.socket()
    if not self.portEntry.get():
        portInfo = 80
    try:
        conn = socket.socket()
        name = socket.gethostbyname(serverInfo)
        conn.connect((name,portInfo))
        ans = conn.recv(2048)
        self.outputWindow.insert(END, "Connection successful: \n \
        port:{}, server:{} ('{}'), '{}' \n".format(portInfo, name, serverInfo, \
        ans))
        return
    except Exception as e:
        self.outputWindow.insert(END, str(e) + "\n")
```

I originally thought it was because there was now timeout, but as you can see, I added a 5 second timeout in the very first line of the code. I assumed it was because the application was having some sort of trouble connecting, but I checked Windows task manager, and under the network section there was no activity. I also ran the program in Ubuntu 14.04 but got the same results.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The socket waits for 2,048 bytes from the server (`conn.recv(2048)`) and I guess they never arrive.

Comment: From reading the docs, one might expect `socket.setdefaulttimeout(5)` to make `recv()` fail after 5 seconds in this case.

Comment: I tried toning down the number of bytes, first to 1024, then to 512, then to 128, but I get the same results.

Comment: recv() will return as soon as it has any bytes to give you; it won't wait until it has exactly the number of bytes you specified.  (it won't return *more* than the number of bytes you specified, though)  Are you sure that recv() is being called?  You might be blocked in the connect() (or even potentially in the gethostbyname()) call instead.